# Form Array from Drupal server response for <ion-list>

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

What I want is accordion list in Ionic http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epPPbm . Problem is in data which I receive from server on Drupal. Lets say my html file is like this

```
    <ion-list ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <ion-item class="item item-stable item-icon-left">
            {{category.name}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-list ng-repeat="subcategory in category.subcategories">
            <ion-item class="item item-positive item-icon-left">
                {{subcategory.name}}
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-list>
```

From server I get this

```
[{"tid":"17","depth":0,"parents":["0"]},{"tid":"12","depth":1,"parents":["15","17"]},{"tid":"1","depth":0,"parents":["0"]},{"tid":"15","depth":0,"parents":["0"]},{"tid":"16","depth":1,"parents":["15"]},{"tid":"13","depth":1,"parents":["15"]},{"tid":"12","depth":1,"parents":["15","17"]},{"tid":"11","depth":0,"parents":["0"]},{"tid":"14","depth":0,"parents":["0"]}]
```

Here depth `0` and `1` mean category and subcategory accordingly. `Parents` is array of parents `tid` of subcategory. I need form array from response for my html view. Now I do this and it is very complicated

```
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; ++i) {
        if (categories[i].depth == 0)
            $scope.categories.push(categories[i]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; ++i)
        $scope.categories[i].subcategories = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; ++i) {
        if (categories[i].depth == 1) {
            for (var j = 0; j < categories[i].parents.length; ++j) {
                for (var k = 0; k < categories.length; ++k) {
                    if (categories[k].tid === categories[i].parents[j]) {
                        $scope.categories[k].subcategories.push(categories[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

May be there is more simple way to do this.

Comment: Update your codepen to include your complicated code please.

Comment: I updated codepen, check, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to create the nested category and subcategory lists you aren't going to be able to avoid a nested loop of some kind, but I do believe you can make the code more readable (and faster) by creating a hash lookup to build the arrays. For example:

```
// build a lookup and add the primary categories to the scope
var tidLookup = {};
angular.forEach(categories, function(cat){
    if(cat.depth === 0){
        cat.subcategories = [];
        $scope.categories.push(cat);
    }
    tidLookup[cat.tid] = cat;
});

// go through each subcategory and add it to the appropriate parent
angular.forEach(categories, function(cat){
    angular.forEach(cat.parents, function(parent){
        if(tidLookup[parent]){
            tidLookup[parent].subcategories.push(cat);
        }
    });
});
```

I have updated your codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epPQpZ

Also note that the duplicates in your codepen results are because you have duplicated your example data array.

---

Update:

If you need to deal with duplicate subcategories coming from your server I would either try and remove the duplicates on get, or just keep a second hash lookup of all processed subcategories, which can be checked while processing.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your way is much more smart. I also wanted to say that duplicates are sent to me from the server so I have to deal with them.

Comment: Dealing with duplicates makes it a little bit more interesting. I have updated my answer with one possibility. Good luck.

Comment: Now I use the first of your proposed methods, thnx for idea with hash lookup.